# What font is used here on David Guetta's T-shirts?

Tags: font-identification

What is this font on David Guetta's T-shirts?

[image: David Guetta T-shirt text]

"Its the way you love me - I wanna go crazy". The same streaky-paint style font is used on the David Guetta album, "One more love".

Comment: Try a font identification site such as http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: If the below answer answered your question please accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Found it!  It's [**Levi Brush**](http://www.dafont.com/levibrush.font) by [Levi Szekeres](http://loremipsum.ro/):

[image: Levi Brush sample text]

The font is free for personal use, but commercial use requires the author's permission.  I also found [this comments page on the dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/font-comment.php?file=levibrush), where the font's author writes:

> "The Guetta guy didn't bothered paying to use the font, but probably it's not his fault, he must have some ignorant designer. Ironic, if you think of all the copyright issue the musicians have these days."

Comment: Good work :) and I know a lot of david guetta haters who'll enjoy getting angry at that fact about the font licensing. If the font designer sends the label a cease and desist I recon they'd quickly offer a reasonable settlement